# autofs mac os x afp not loading as correct user?

Tags: mac-osx, afp, autofs, automount

I am way out of my depth, and I am trying to get all of my nodes on a cluster to mount a drive on my head node.  I am using OS X 10.6.

I've got `/etc/auto_master` and `/etc/auto_afp` configured according to Apple's "Autofs: Automatically Mounting Network File Shares in Mac OS X" White Paper:

/etc/auto_master

```
+auto_master            # Use directory service
/net                    -hosts          -nobrowse,hidefromfinder,nosuid
/home                   auto_home       -nobrowse,hidefromfinder
/Network/Servers        -fstab
/-                      -static
/-                      auto_afp
```

/etc/auto_afp

```
/Volumes/userA  -fstype=afp afp://userA:pword@head-node.local:/
/Volumes/userB  -fstype=afp afp://userB:pword@head-node.local:/
```

I am logged into a compute-node as userA.  automount appears to mount both `/Volumes/userA` and `/Volumes/userB` to `head-node.local:/Users/userA/Documents/` even though I have usernames, passwords, and user-directory specified in the afp url.  If I go and login with Finder - it mounts userB appropriately.

File sharing and cd/dvd sharing is enabled on all computers involved.

Am I doing the right thing, and if so, what did I do wrong?

-Stephen

Comment: What version of Mac OS X are you running? There are quite big variances in automount behaviour between versions. On Snow Leopard, at least, I use the “NFS Mounts” GUI in Disk Utility to configure mine.

Comment: I'm running 10.6.  Plus its not a NFS server - it could be anything from a DVD on another machine to a laptop or something else.  I kindof need to be able to modify it programmatically... unless the Mac OS X API has an interface for Disk Utility?  I originally tried to mount it with mount_afp but that continually gave me -5000, -5019, and -5023 errors depending on the username, sudo, etc. that I used.